# Flash AS3 IF statement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I have made a flash application in which you need to match an object. So below, I am setting the objects (ship, obj1,obj2,obj3) to targets (t1,t2,t3,t4). I am then setting the score to 0.

```
private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _check);
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemovedFromStage);

        ship.setTarget(t1,shipObject);

        obj1.setTarget(t2,1Object);

        obj2.setTarget(t3,2Object);

        obj3.setTarget(t4,3Object);

        score = 0;
                    scorecounter.text =" SCORE:" + score.toString();

    }
```

next, I created a function which finds out if the object, in this case the ship, has reached the target.

```
function _check(event:TimerEvent):void 
    {
        if(ship.done)
           {     
              score += 1;
              scorecounter.text =" SCORE:" + score.toString();
           }

            }
```

This works correctly, because once the user drags the ship to the target, it adds +1 to the score, but then an issue occurs. I have more than one object/target. This means when the user completes moving the ship to the target, any other objects that become moved instantly give a +1 to the score, because the object ship is still at the target.

Anybody got any ideas how to fix this?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can you post more code?  You don't give enough context in the code posted.  Specifically when does this code run and in what context? (in a class file of your target objects? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... a little difficult to capture what is going on without the full code, but here is a shot:

I notice that your "ship" object has a property "done", so I am guessing you created a variable/property on the object called "done", which makes me think that you can add another property to the ship like "scored"

so your code might look something like this:

```
if ((ship.done) && (ship.scored == false)){
  ship.scored = true;
  score += 1;
  scorecounter.text = "SCORE:" + score.toString();
}
```

Is that possible for you?

Comment: Brilliant! I Just created the ship.scored and it worked a treat! I gave you best answer. Thanks a lot bud.